# Boolean modifier cuts out more than it's supposed to

Tags: modeling, modifiers, error

I'm modeling my mouse in Blender and I'm trying to create some indentation with a boolean modifier. The modifier is set to difference and with my logic it should just cut out the parts where the two objects (mouse body & the boolean object displayed in wireframe) intersect.

[image]

However, when I switch back to object mode it looks like this:

[image]

I've tried recalculating the normals and removing doubles on both objects but nothing's changed. Any idea?

Here's the .blend file if it helps:
[desk.blend in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2tvb82s5f40l7j/desk.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Boolean operations do not work well on non-manifold geometry.

Comment: I figured it out. The boolean object was clipping itself. Changing that seemed to fix the problem.